# Using environment variables when adding paths on MacOS

Tags: bash, macos, go, path, environment-variables

I've found myself with the need to add a new path permanently in all terminal sessions on my Mac. Specifically I want to add the contents of my $GOPATH/bin to my $PATH.

So far I think my options are to either:

1. Add it to my $HOME/.bash_profile file using export syntax.
2. Create a file containing the path to add in the /etc/paths.d directory.

I've settled on option 2, because I like the idea of just adding files with one line in whenever I want a new path added permanently.

I have tried adding in a file `/etc/profile.d/gopath` containing `~/code/go/bin`. This works. However, what I'd like to do is evaluate the environment variable, `$GOPATH/bin` such that if I decide to change my $GOPATH I only have to change the variable. However, that just adds the literal words "$GOPATH/bin" to my path, it doesn't actually add the directory to my path. The $GOPATH bash environment variable is currently set in my `~/.bashrc` file.

Some questions:

- Why doesn't the $ syntax evaluate in the $PATH or setting of $PATH? Is that not bash?
- What comes first, the inclusion of `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile` or `/etc/profile.d`? It is reasonable of me to think that the environment variable would be there when setting the $PATH?
- How can I have this environment variable be evaluated and substituted if it is feasible?

Thanks for your help. All my searches don't seem to come up with the above answers.

Comment: Put your env variables in `~/.bash_profile` (or `~/.profile`). `$PATH` should be evaluated normally, so please show an example if you can't get it to work.

Comment: I don't think `/etc/paths.d` supports environment variables. Also worth noting is that your `$GOPATH` is defined inside your base profile, which is probably loaded **after** `/etc/paths.d`, meaning it would be undefined. Definitely add `GOPATH` to your profile

Comment: Thanks Max, I think you're right although I didn't find any documentation/proof other than the above behaviour. Anyway thanks for the comment.